# Connect to MS SQL Server on Arch Linux

Tags: sql-server

I installed on my arch machine `mssql-server` and `mssql-tools` via `yaourt`. I started the server from `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr` and tried to connect with my credentials, but with no luck. I found [this](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ms-sql-server-centos-ubuntu-linux/) article which says to connect with the command `sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'YourPasswordHere'`, but it didn't work either. The error message says:

> 2017-07-06 21:57:28.25 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State:
>   7.
>
> 2017-07-06 21:57:28.25 Logon       Login failed for user 'SA'. Reason:
>   An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]

I tried with blank password, with Password123 and with my user's password but the message was the same.

Has anyone managed to connect and if yes what was the default password?

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have SSMS installed? Can you connect there?

Comment: I didn't find SSMS for arch linux. Can you give me the url please?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-manage-ssms

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. This is to connect from windows to Linux server. I installed ms-server on my machine which is running Arch Linux. I don't have windows. I need a solution that doesn't require windows environment.

Comment: Not to be rude, but if you can't use the IDE designed for the database how are you going to administer it? Sounds impossible. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe from the console. I have no idea :P

Comment: @JacobH sqlcmd is the CLI utility provided by Microsoft. In it one writes T-SQL, which allows an administrator to administer the database. Pointing and clicking isn't the only way to interact with your database.

Comment: @JNevill I could browse the internet with a command line utility too.

Comment: @JacobH Yes... yes you could...

Comment: @VassilisPallas [Check out this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/55) seems like good advice about special symbols in password (guessing here since I don't know your pass).

Comment: @JNevill thanks for the tip but my password contains only letters and numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it. I had to run this command `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup` in order to set the password for the SA user. Now I can connect.